# Retrieve the data from local json-server in React

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I have a react application and I am using json-server, however, I want to use the data in the json-server **on my host**. When I built the application, it couldn't retrieve the data because json-server is run locally.

To be more clear, I have db.json file and images in my local json-server. And in my react application, I use a base URL like that: http://localhost:3001/ to get all data from local json-server and it works on localhost. However as I said I want to be able to run this application and retrieve the all data on a real server, my host.

What should I do to retrieve this data on a real server?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your json-server on a hosting service (like Heroku for example), then replace your localhost:3001 with the remote server url.

It looks like json-server can serve static folder as well, so it might be possible to build your react application into a ‘public’ folder and deploy both on one same server

> You can use JSON Server to serve your HTML, JS and CSS, simply create a ./public directory or use --static to set a different static files directory.

[json-server readme](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: db.json and other data based files are deployed on Heroku, however, when I want to add my **public** folder which includes my images folder, server crashes on Heroku. As you know in json-server you can create a public folder which you want to access to assets.